# Change color of line containing specified string in RichTextbox

Tags: colors, richtextbox, lines

I'm trying to have a RTB show any line containing `foo` be red. Here's what I've attempted so far:

```
 string foo = "foo";

            if (richTextBox1.Lines.Contains(foo))
            {
                richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.Lines.Contains(foo);
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;                  
            }
```

Is there a more effective way of going about this or is anyone able to see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is with `Select()` function

Here's how you can do it:

```
string foo = "foo";
int lineNum = 0;
foreach (string line in richTextBox2.Lines)
{
    if (line.Contains(foo))
    {
        richTextBox2.Select(richTextBox2.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineNum), line.Length);
        richTextBox2.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
    }
    lineNum++;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I will try this and report back.